# How to change color(red) of onsale price only in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

How to change color(red) of onsale price only in woocommerce?
I try with CSS, but I need change in the separate page not in the shop. I need hook from Woocommerce. How it write?

Answer (score 0):

She shuld have a proper css file, use code inspector to find path to css .
also you can connect proper css or make a check in js or php

```
js//
if(window.location.href.match('mypage')){
//you cann append css file
}
php//
if(preg_match('/mypage/', $_SERVER['RQUEST_URI'])){
?>
<style></style>
<?
}
```

Comment: I mean , if I see onsale product and it ia not emty I use css with red color , I dont know how to write, for example :

Comment: if (empty($sales_price)) {
            echo '<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.$regular_price.'&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></span> </span>';
        } else {
            echo '<span class="price"><del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.$regular_price.'&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.$sales_price.'&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></span></ins></span>';
        }

Comment: Thanks for example with js and php, but then I go from page to see product, this product in the shop, I see black price , not red